# How to drop the index after creating the csv file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to select couple of columns based on column heading with wild card and one more column. When I execute the below code , I am getting the expected result, but there is an index which is appearing. how to drop the index . Any suggestions.

infile:

```
dir,name,ct1,cn1,ct2,cn2
991,name1,em,a@email.com,ep,1234
999,name2,em,b@email.com,ep,12345
872,name3,em,c@email.com,ep,123456
```

here is the code which I used.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('infile.csv')
df_new=df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith('c')]
df_new_1=pd.read_csv('name.csv', usecols= ['dir'])
df_merge=pd.concat([df_new,df_new_1],axis=1, join="inner")
df_merge.to_csv('outfile.csv')
```

Comment: you can reset the index `df.reset_index()` or define that one of the columns of your data is the index `df.set_index('my_column_name')`, but a dataframe always has an index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass false for index when you save to csv :

```
df_merge.to_csv('outfile.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: It worked good. Is there any better option to merge "df_new=df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith('c')]
df_new_1=pd.read_csv('name.csv', usecols= ['dir'])" to one ?